# How can I subset a dataframe based on two simultaneously fulfilled conditions in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, subset

This is my first question on stack overflow, so please let me know if there is further information that would be required to answer the question. I have started learning R very recently so I kindly ask for your patience.

I have a data frame Df1 which I want to subset/filter based on two **simultaneous** conditions:

- Is the company code also present in Df2?
- in this case, is the date also the same for the two dataframes?

I have tried the following code

```
Sub <- subset(Df1, Df1$CompanyCode %in% Df2$CompanyCode & year(Df1$Date) %in% Df2$Year)
```

I think I know where the problem is but I don't know how to fix it. I think the formula above checks individually both "%in%" conditions and therefore returns to many cases.

To give a concrete example (see below; **EDIT: as requested now as dput output**): it would **expect to not have row #4** in Df1 in my result because there is no matching case in Df2. However, it is part of the resulting subset. I guess because it can find a match for both company code and the date **individually**, i.e. it can find company "B" in Df" and it can find the year 2016 in Df2. However, this is not what I want because there is no perfect match, having these two conditions fulfilled **at the same time**.

Df1 (Input1):

```
structure(list(CompanyCode = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D"), 
    Date = structure(c(16800, 17166, 16800, 17166, 16800, 17166
    ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Df2 (Input 2):

```
structure(list(CompanyCode = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D"), Year = c(2015L, 
2016L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Sub (Actual Output):

```
structure(list(CompanyCode = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D"), 
    Date = structure(c(16800, 17166, 16800, 17166, 16800, 17166
    ), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

ExpectedSub (Expected Output):

```
structure(list(CompanyCode = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D"), Date = structure(c(16800, 
17166, 16800, 16800, 17166), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me out here. Hopefully this example made my problem clear.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide your input data as the output from `dput()` rather than as images.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `paste` `CompanyCode` and year value to create an unique key between and use `%in%` to keep only those keys which are present `df2`.

```
result <- subset(df1, paste(CompanyCode, format(Date, '%Y')) %in% 
                      paste(df2$CompanyCode, df2$Year))
result

#  CompanyCode       Date
#1           A 2015-12-31
#2           A 2016-12-31
#3           B 2015-12-31
#5           C 2015-12-31
```

Comment: thank you, it worked well (especially because I was able to add other conditions).

Answer (score 2):

one more way..

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% mutate(Year = year(as.Date(Date))) %>%
  right_join(df2, by = c("CompanyCode" = "CompanyCode", "Year" = "Year"))

  CompanyCode       Date Year
1           A 2015-12-31 2015
2           A 2016-12-31 2016
3           B 2015-12-31 2015
4           C 2015-12-31 2015
5           D 2016-12-31 2016
```